# Tracking (External) Downloads

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

A few external sites (not under our direct control) host direct links to download our binaries (Mac and PC). To illustrate, *siteA* puts two links e.g. `www.mysite.com/PC.exe` and `www.mysite.com/Mac.dmg`; and the same on *siteB*.

What is the best possible way to track # of downloads using Google Analytics? Ideally, I'd like to be able to drill down # of downloads of PC *and* Mac for each site. That is, something like (3 PC and 5 Mac downloads from *siteA*; 1 PC and 2 Mac downloads from *siteB*).

The one I can think of is to create an "interstitial" page where the external sites point to (by passing a query parameter of which binary to download e.g. `www.mysite.com/x.html?binary=PC.exe`, which will then trigger an event tracking script (Google Analytics). However, this approach will not give us the info about where the request was coming from. Maybe I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

2 options, both using onclick :

(1) Create a [virtual Pageview](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html#VirtualPageviews) (not recommended) :

> ```
> <a href="http://www.example.com/downloads/PC.exe"  onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/downloads/PC.exe');"> PC Download </a>
> ```

(2) Use [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) (recommended):

> ```
> <a href="http://www.example.com/downloads/PC.exe" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Download - Pc.exe','Label', optional_value]);">Play</a>
> ```

Google Analytics recommends the latter, but there are pros and cons for both methods :

- Using Virtual PageViews will increase the number of page views and distort metrics like Pages/Visits, Bounce Rate, and related metrics. By contrast, Events are tracked separately, but also count towards Bounce Rate (a Visit consisting of only 1 page and a download will not be considered a Bounce)
- Event Tracking is more flexible, as you can choose a Category, Action, Label and a Value for the Event, and view them independently from Pages. However, that means you need to think carefully about how you want to use the data model.
- Event Tracking has the following default metrics : Total Events, Unique Events, Event Value and Average Value.
- Pages have the following default metrics : Pageviews, Unique Pageviews, Avg. Time on Page, Bounce Rate, % Exit.
- An interesting 'bug' is that filters applied to URLs/hostnames will not filter out Events. In fact, there is no way to filter out Events - they will show up in all Profiles. Problematic if you use Profile filtering a lot.

Best way to go is to test both options and make up your mind after you see the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this is *not* relevant to the situation described above because we cannot use virtual pageview or event tracking on the external sites (in fact, those sites will not be using the same GA script). I think the solution needs to completely "reside" on our site, in this example `www.example.com`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand that you have not control over these sites.

Comment: So yeah, you can circumvent the fact that you never see the download in your tracking by linking to a redirect page instead that triggers the download and a tracking script. You should see the referring site in your Traffic sources report if you track the download page using _trackPageView.

Comment: I don't quite get your last statement. I assume that's *only if* we had control over the external site , right?